# Big optimization with equality constrains

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to solve  a quite big optimization problem, where time matters, but I stucked with the understanding in the vast amount of "R" packages, so I would like to ask the community directly about this problem.

I want to minimize a function:

```
F=(x-y)^2
```

where y is  a given, pre defined vector of 8000 values.
So, I'm searching for the 8000 x-es.
I've got a matrix of A (which is basically a dummy variable matrix), with nrow=8, ncol=8000.
I also have a vector b, with 8 given values.
So, I want to want to solve the following problem:

```
min(x-y)^2

s.t:
A*x=b
```

Theoretically I understand everything, but somehow I fail to incorporate the F into any package, where equallity constrains are allowed.
Also (and because I've no idea, what will be the processing time), I would like to ask you, what would you do, if:

F= abs(x-y)

because if the minimalization of the quadratic function takes to long, this second option would also satisfy me.
The data is confidential, but privately (and a bit differently) I'll send it, if it's necessary for the solution.

Edit nr.1:

ok, i'll be more specific this time
i've got 2 years of data (that is the 8000 measurment, each year contains 4000 measurments)
each year have q1, q2, q3, q4, which happened somehow in a past (but will be specified as optimum in the future, to achive some goals)
so, this is my b vector, the criteria that the optimization has to meet.

made up numbers

```
b<-c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
```

i have got a matrix A, which is a binary matrix, indicates where are we in the time, q1,q2, etc
let say, that one quarter of the year is 1 days long, so:
(there is 7 zero in a vector, because we are talkin about 2 years here, and only one quarter)

```
a<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
u<-c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
c<-c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
d<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

from this point, another year comes in, with another q1, that is why the binary wont jumps back to the first place

```
e<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
f<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
g<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
h<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)


A<-cbind(a,u,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

this is a bit bad way to represent the data, I can trick you, because the length and the width is the
same in the matrix, but remember, in the original data everything is fine for matrix multiplication
the width of A, and the length of x is 8000

there is a planed way, how things sholud go in each Q, that is the "y", which is given.

made up numbers

```
y<-c(10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18)
```

so basically, i want to stuck to the plan, as much as I can, but to achive criteria b, that is whay I want to minimize
the differences between the planned and the x values,

```
min F (Ax-y)^2
s.t: A*x=b
```

Hope it's clearer,i reduced the dimension of the problem, this way it may
seem unfeasible
(its dumb, i know :)

Comment: Craft a [mcve] with smallest size, show your expected output, as is I don't get what your question is in fact.

Comment: After a talk in chat maybe [this package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/solve-methods.html) could be of help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll check it.

Comment: I also edited my question

Comment: I still don't get a word about the target, but that's probably because I'm not statistician :) But now the question sounds more clear and of use for future readers (I mainly still have a little problem between criteria b and vector p, if I understand properly they are the same beast, may worth fixing the naming in text/code in the wole Q to be consistent). If you find an answer feel free to answer yourself here :)

Comment: well, the p and b pretty much the same, i just changed b to p, because i used b to hold a binary vector in my first edit, but i'll edit again :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is nothing to optimize. E.g. with your data set:

```
> b<-c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
> a<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
> u<-c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
> c<-c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
> d<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
> 
> e<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
> f<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
> g<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
> h<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
> 
> A<-cbind(a,u,c,d,e,f,g,h)
> x <- solve(A,b)
> x
  a   u   c   d   e   f   g   h 
-20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
```

It would be more interesting if there were some degrees of freedom left to play with x and make it as close as y as possible,

Comment: But this way we just solve x, it has to stay close to y. I was searching all day long, I think my problem is a quadratic optimization problem

Comment: If x is close to y it will violate Ax=b.

Comment: I rephrased my question here, based on the knowledge that I learned today:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351012/quadprog-quadratic-programming-form